# How could I forward my domain to auto scale group's instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS horrible documentation is killing me T_T

I set up a auto scaling group  with my prepared images.

Then I can not found any way to point my domain `sample.co` to my instances.

I've setup the domain in route 53, What should I do now ?

I still can not get what do the `load balancing` and `auto scaling` do in the left bar on the console.

I just want to get the `domain` can point to my auto scaling group's instances.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Route 53, click "Create Record Set."

Enter a hostname (such as "www") in the "Name" box, or leave it blank for the naked domain.

Set "Type" to "A."

Set "Alias" to "Yes."

Select the hostname of your ELB in the "available targets" list.

Save the changes.

...as explained in the "horrible" documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html

Comment: Just to add to this, it looks like the OP hasn't yet attached their autoscale group to an ELB; they'll need to do that first.

Comment: @BestPractices,  good point, if correct.  I assumed  it was there, based on "Health Check Type: ELB."

Comment: I assumed it wasn't attached because in the Autoscale group screenshot, under Load Balancing, there is no load balancer listed.

Answer (score 1):

in route53, "create a hosted zone" then "create a record set" then "create a record set" point your root domain to the ELB "select A record" and "select Alias" to yes and use the DNS name of the load balancer.